# Simultaneous Fit of Two ODE's to data in Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, ode

NOTE: [Fit differential equation with scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767265/fit-differential-equation-with-scipy) has been tried and a few other answers also. None seem to work.

I have two data sets d1 & d2 which I am trying to fit with two coupled ODE's (solver given below). d1 and d2 correspond to lab data for an experiment control & treatment.

When I do the fit for the first ODE (only control case), it works fine and I get the desired parameters. When I do the same for the treatment case, using the fit parameters obtained from the control case, my code doesn't seem to optimize anything whatsoever.

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import scipy

d1 = [113.75981939,  224.732254  ,  437.00727486,  533.3249591 ,900.19498288, 1460.34662166, 2276.34857406, 3288.90246842,3888.70188293, 5102.45452895]

d2 = [118.69478959,  201.30146742, 287.50835473, 437.70461121,511.9610845,  982.88626039, 1115.37610645, 1235.95872766,1622.57717685, 1776.95184626]

time = [ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]

'''
#ODE's
dS/dt = r*S*(1-(S/K))-(kappa*S*T)
dT/dt = a*S-d*T
'''

#Curve Fit Section

#First get r,K from control data, i.e, case where kappa = 0
def func(y,t,r,K):
    S = y
    dydt = r*S*(1-(S/K))
    return dydt


y0 = [100]
t = time
guess = [0.3,5000] #[guess_r,guess_K]

def fit(params):
    r,K = params
    test_solve = odeint(func,y0,t,args=(r,K))
    return np.linalg.norm(test_solve[:,0]-d1)


res = scipy.optimize.minimize(fit,np.array(guess))

r,K = res.x #Returns the r, K parameter values that fit the control data perfectly.

#Curve fit for treatment case

#ODE Solver for Control and Treatment Model

def func(y,t,r,K,a,kappa,d):
    S,T = y
    dydt = [r*S*(1-(S/K))-(kappa*S*T),a*S-d*T]
    return dydt
    

y0 = [100,0]
t = time
guess_t = [r,K,2,3,0.01]

#Fitting the experimental data set

def fit(params):
    r,K,a,d,kappa = params
    test_solve = odeint(func,y0,t,args=(r,K,a,d,kappa))
    return np.linalg.norm(test_solve[:,0]-d2)


res2 = scipy.optimize.minimize(fit,np.array(guess_t))
```

result - res2.x is the same as the guess_t array - no change,i.e, no fit

When I try the second fit after using the parameters obtained from the first, I get no meaningful result. It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT : The parameter values one gets (from a Matlab fit) - `r=0.2629, K=7625.2, a=7.845, d=189.49. k =0.0026`. The code above returns very similar values for `r & K` but not for the other 3 parameters (`a,kappa,d`). Not sure what is happening.

EDIT 2: I keep getting this error. Any idea what is going wrong?
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py:247: ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning

Comment: Kinda looks like your initial guess might not be very good. When I run your `guess_t`, through `fit`, and print `test_solve[:,0]`, I get something very different than the data `d2`

Comment: @nicholaswogan - it doesn't seem to matter. No matter what values of guess_t passed, the inputs for `a, kappa and d` never change. If the result from `scipy.optimze.minimize` manages to fit the data set (minimize the error), the values of a,d and kappa will change and be returned by `res2.x`. They never do and I don't know why that is. 

I also know what the actual values should be since this fitting has been done in Matlab too - even if I were to pass them through the fit function, there is no effect. I have added the values I should obtain in the code snippet above.

Comment: one problem is that you are integrating starting at `t=1`, but my guess is that you want to start at `t=0`? When I print `test_solve[:,0]` the values are super tiny (~1e-15), which is way different than your data d2. The difference between d2 (order ~1e2) and 1e-15 will be tiny numbers, so thus scipy.optimize.minimize will be convinced it has found a minimum. If you think your initial conditions are reasonable then I would guess you have made a mistake in your ODE function`def func(y,t,r,K,a,kappa,d)`?